# Showing two matrices have the same $x$ and $b$ in the equation $Ax = b$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Just a brief preface, this isn't homework or from a textbook, it is from my own curiosity.

Suppose you have a real valued $3\times 3$ invertible matrix $A$ and fix $\vec{b}\neq \vec{0}$ in the equation $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$. Call the solution to this system $\vec{x_{1}} = A^{-1}\vec{b}$.

My question now is if it's always possible to find a matrix $A^{\prime} \neq A$ such that $A^{\prime}$ is invertible, $A^{\prime}\vec{x_{1}} = b$ and the first two rows of $A^{\prime}$ are the same as the first two rows of $A$.

After some playing around, I can get conditions like $A^{\prime}A^{-1} =  A(A^{\prime})^{-1}$ or $(A^{-1}-(A^{\prime})^{-1})\vec{b} = 0$, but I can't really get anywhere meaningful. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If at least one of the two first entries in $b$ are zero then creating an $A'$ is possible by adding some multiple of that row to the last. If both of the first two entries in $b$ are nonzero then there is a particular linear combination of the two first rows of $A$ that do the trick...

Comment: If the third row is a linear combination of the first two then $A^{\prime}$ will not be invertible.

Comment: I meant there is a particular linear combination that you should add to the last row.

Comment: Ah, I got it now. Thank you